# Gnuplot re Plotting lines after restart count

Tags: file, gnuplot

I am quite new in Gnuplot, so sorry if the question could be silly, but i have not found the solution yet.

I have a data file with this structure:

```
timestep=0
   1 -1.367+00 -2.538572773308e-01
   2 -1.351097897106e+00 -2.382132334519e-01
   3 -1.372764576847e+00 -1.205983667912e-01
   4 -1.33451163582e+00 -2.3438654806e-01
   5 -2.414239606e+00 -2.683590584894e-01
   6 -4.425446031e+00 -3.246530421864e-01
   7 -6.438461740e+00 -4.589039346035e-01
   ...
timestep=1
 ...
timestep=2
...
```

So for every timesteps the count of iterations (what i want on x axis), restarts.
There will be many time steps, so if I plot all the timesteps together it is difficult to see every lines. 
So the questions is: how can i plot the line of just one timestep?

The number of iterations of every time step is different.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple data blocks in a single file and a single plot + Markers for each block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658283/multiple-data-blocks-in-a-single-file-and-a-single-plot-markers-for-each-block)

Comment: See Ethan's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52881511/2604213 which uses a new feature from the recent 5.2.5 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question looks like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658283/multiple-data-blocks-in-a-single-file-and-a-single-plot-markers-for-each-block). 
Nevertheless, the idea is to plot every block separately:

```
plot for[in=0:2] 'file' index in u 1:2 w lines t columnheader(1)
```

Note, that you need to wrap every header using double quotation marks.

If you need to have a separate output for every block, than you need a `do for` construction looking like this:

```
do for [i=0:2] {
set output sprintf("%d.png", i)
plot 'file' index i u 1:2 not
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've checked it one more time, here is my minimal script:

```
set term png size 800, 600
set output "out.png"
plot for[in=0:1] 'file' index in u 1:2 w lp t columnheader(1)
```

And my "file" file:

```
"timestep=0"
1 0
2 3
3 2
4 1
5 6



"timestep=1"
1 4
2 3
3 9
4 6
5 3
```

The output has to look like this: [image]

Comment: Unfortunately....gnuplot> plot for[in=0:2] 'file' index in u 1:2 w lines t columnheader(1)
                 ^
         invalid expression

Comment: @federicorovere  Could you please check the updated answer?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use `plot <filename> every`, more details [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node121.html) and another stackoverflow description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526481/gnuplot-shortest-way-to-ignore-first-line-in-datafile).

That way you can choose to plot not just one timestep; but say every second timestep, or every third as you choose.

Comment: `every` doesn't help here